# How to detect one line in dataset with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-2.7

hi iam working on project for detecting heart failure by using supervised ML algorithms. know i have complete my work and got an accuracy but i need to add something else to my work which is how to  detect only one line in the dataset to see if the patient will die or not? so when i enter the line number will detect the final result. Iam trying this code but its not working

```
  Rf0 = input('Enter No. of Patient?')
  Rf=int(Rf0)
  face = N1.iloc[Rf]
  poly_pred1 = knn2.predict(face)
  print('The person is {}'.format(poly_pred2))
```

also i have tried this one

```
  Rf = input('Enter No. of Patient')
  poly_pred2 = regressor2.predict(N11[Rf-1:Rf,:])
  print('The person is {}'.format(poly_pred2))
```

please any one can help?

Comment: Your first code has an error. You save prediction as poly_pred1, but later print poly_pred2. I don't know if this makes sense, but I would predict on all dataset as new column and then filter patient from dataset to see his prediction.

Comment: thank you sir but now i need to know how to enter the patient number to give me the result if the patient will die  or not please help i appreciate

Answer (score 0):

```
Rf = input('Enter No. of Patient')   
poly_pred2 = regressor2.predict(N11[Rf-1:Rf,:])   
print('The person is {}'.format(poly_pred2))
```

can you please give the type of

> poly_pred2 variable.

Ex : **print(type(poly_pred2))**

Comment: thank you for answering actually this is the type     <class 'numpy.ndarray'>     please sir i need to know how to enter the patient number to have the result please help